# How to get individual numbers inside list which is inside another list in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm completely at a loss on trying to figure out how to get the individual numbers inside in a list

Here is my code:

```
infinity = 1000000 
invalid_node = -1  

class Node:
    previous = invalid_node
    distFromSource = infinity
    visited = False

def populateNetwork(fileName):

    network = []
    networkFile = open(fileName, "r")
    for line in networkFile:
        network.append(map(int, line.strip().split(',')))
    return network

def populateNodeTable(network, StartNode):
    nodeTable = []
    for node in network:
        nodeTable.append(Node())
    nodeTable[StartNode].distFromSource = 0
    nodeTable[StartNode].visited = True
    return nodeTable

network = populateNetwork('network.txt')
nodeTable = populateNodeTable(network, 1)
nodeTable2 = populateNodeTable(network, 2)
print "Visited Nodes"
for node in nodeTable:
    print node.previous, node.distFromSource, node.visited
print
print "This is what is inside network"
for line in network:
    print line

print
print "what is inside index 6"
print network[6]
```

Here is the output:

```
Visited Nodes
-1 1000000 False
-1 0 True
-1 1000000 False
-1 1000000 False
-1 1000000 False
-1 1000000 False
-1 1000000 False

This is what is inside network
[0, 2, 4, 1, 6, 0, 0]
[2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0]
[4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
[6, 5, 0, 1, 0, 5, 5]
[0, 0, 5, 1, 5, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0]

what is inside index 6
[0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0]
```

My question is, how do I get the individual numbers inside an index to be used to calculate? So for example index[1] contains "0, 2, 4, 1, 6, 0, 0" and I am going to use these numbers to do addition so 0+2+4+1+6+0+0 = 13. I'm really confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print network[0] # 0, 2, 4, 1, 6, 0, 0

print network[0][0] # 0
print network[0][1] # 2
print network[0][2] # 4

for x in network[0]:
   print x
# 0
# 2
# 4
# 1
# 6
# 0
# 0

print sum(network[0]) # 13
```